# Elementary problem about proving non-equivalence of representations

Tags: representation-theory

I'm trying to solve the following exercise.

**Exercise.** Let $E=F(x)$ where $x$ is transcendental over $F$. Prove the group (I assume this means subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(E)$) generated by $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $ is not equivalent to any subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(K)$ where $K$ is a finite extension of $F$.

I haven't studied representations before so I'm a bit lost here. First of all, I take it "equivalent groups" means equivalent as linear groups.

1. Since isomorphic representations must have linearly isomorphic underlying spaces, I guess I'm (not) looking for an intertwining $F$-linear isomorphism $f:F(x)\oplus F(x)\cong K\oplus K$. Is that correct?
2. I guess I'm supposed to reach a contradiction here, so I should suppose there's an intertwining $F$-linear isomorphism $f$ as above i.e satisfying $g\cdot f(v)=f(g\cdot v)$. I don't understand how to get a contradiction with the transcendence of $x$ over $F$.

---

**Context.** The exercise appears in a set of notes written by the lecturer in a basic course "topics in linear groups". Paraphrasing, the relevant section begins like this: Given a field extension $E/F$ and a group $G$, an $F$-linear rep of $G$ extends to an $E$-linear rep of $E$. Now I quote the first line that confuses me:

> If a representation $\psi:G\to \mathrm{GL}_n(E)$ is equivalent to a representation $\rho\to \mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ then...

The author motivates the section by noting that for equivalent such representations (over $E,F$ with $E/F$), the traces take values in $F$, and raises the question of the converse. That is, if the traces of an $E$-linear rep take values in $F$, is the $E$-linear rep equivalent to some $F$-linear rep?

"Equivalent representations" were only defined when they're over the same field (just isomorphic reps). Maybe the meaning of "equivalence" over difference fields should have been my question.

---

**Added.** As suggested by Eric Wofsey - a reasonable definition would be "having conjugate images inside the general linear group of the vector space with scalars extended to an algebraic closure of $E$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure without more context, but I would guess that "equivalent groups" here means conjugate subgroups of $GL_2(\bar{E})$ where $\bar{E}$ is an algebraic closure of $E$.  So, writing $G$ for the subgroup described, the goal is to prove that there does not exist any finite extension $K$ of $F$ and $a\in GL_2(\bar{E})$ such that $aga^{-1}$ has entries in $K$ for all $g\in G$.

As a hint for how to do this, the matrices in $G$ become easier to deal with when you subtract the identity matrix from them.  A full solution is hidden below.

> Let $g=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $h=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.  Then $g,h\in G$, $g,h\neq I$, and $x(g-I)=h-I$.  This equation is preserved by conjugation, so any subgroup equivalent to $G$ contains elements $g',h'\neq I$ such that $x(g'-I)=h'-I$  But then any field containing the entries of both $g'$ and $h'$ must contain $x$, since a nonzero entry of $h'-I$ divided by the corresponding entry of $g'-I$ is $x$.  In particular, it is impossible for both $g'$ and $h'$ to have entries in $K$ if $K$ is a finite extension of $F$.